# MULTI-SESSION RTABMAP PROBLEM

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, 3d-slam, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, i am working with rtabmap, and I want to use multi-session feature of this package to merge local maps. I am following this tutorial [multi-session tutorial](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Multi-session). However, i figured out that besides ***.db*** files of maps, i need the ***multi-session1Hz.ini*** file as well (like in the tutorial).
The tutorial doesn't show how to generate the multi-session1Hz.ini file clearly. Can you tell me how to do that please?

[image: image description]
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386687/multi-session-rtabmap-problem/) by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2021-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With recent rtabmap versions, parameters are saved in the database, so you don't need the ini file. Anyway, the ini can be exported with Window->Preferences->Save settings (*.ini).

At the [top of the page](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Multi-session):

> Update: While this tutorial should still work, it is slightly outdated as maps created with recent RTAB-Map versions don't require an INI file to be merged (parameters are saved in database for convenience). Follow this [multi-session tutorial with RTAB-Map Tango](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Multi-Session-Mapping-with-RTAB-Map-Tango) instead.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2021-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on 2021-11-01**:
Thank you so much, sir!